# How to use Devextreme Pie chart in nativescript?

Tags: angular, nativescript, pie-chart, devextreme

Please follow the below link:
https://js.devexpress.com/Demos/WidgetsGallery/Demo/Charts/Pie/jQuery/Light/

I have to plugin this pie chart in my nativescript project.

Comment: Can you please be more specific?

Comment: I want to use devextreme Piechart in my nativescript-Angular project. I have import : import { DxPieChartModule } from 'devextreme-angular'; for that. But no Pie chart displaying.

Comment: The chart is developed for web applications running inside browser. If you like to use it on NativeScript application, you should do it inside a WebView.

Comment: Chart not yet displaying. is there any other option to display Pie chart using nativescript? i'm not able to display pie chart for large data using NativeScript RadPieChart. Please assist. @Manoj

Comment: Please describe the issue, possibly share a Playground Sample. Simply saying it doesn't work may not help.

Comment: Please Check this link.       
https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=8zpRGL&v=839

Comment: here i have change home.component.html file to below:

deleted RadCartesianChart 
and add RadPieChart.

Comment: And In Home.Component.ts i want to add many items in array. But after i have added length of the array 50+ . Then chart is not working. @Manoj

Comment: I tried adding upto 55 items in your Playground Sample, it renders just fine. If you still have issue, please share the exact version of code where the issue can be reproduced.